# Convert textfield to uppercase

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield

I am trying to force a textfield to convert whatever you enter to uppercase. This is the line that I have been using

```
style: 'text-transform: uppercase'
```

It is working on 90% of my textfield however for one specific textfield, it will not work. It converts whatever you type into a textfield, but then when you tab out of the textfield it reverts back to lowercase for some reason.

here is the full code for the textfield:

```
    {
    id: 'conditionValue',
    header: "Condition Value",
    dataIndex: 'condValue',
    width: 100,
    editor: newExt.form.TextField({
        style: 'text-transform: uppercase'
    }
})
}
```

Comment: When you examine the field with the browser stylesheet tool, what does that show?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without needing jQuery, instead straight in Ext JS:

```
{
    id: 'conditionValue',
    header: "Condition Value",
    dataIndex: 'condValue',
    width: 100,
    editor: newExt.form.TextField({
        listeners:{
           change:function(field){
                field.setValue(field.getValue().toUpperCase());
           }
        }
    })
}
```

That said, the best way to do it in ExtJS is to use `fieldStyle`, e.g. on your texfield:

`fieldStyle: 'text-transform:uppercase'`

Instead of where you currently set the `style`

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/DrjTS/)

Comment: I use the stle instead of fieldStyle because I am using EXT 4.1.1. Also, I tried the code with the listener on it and it did not seem to work at all.

Comment: fieldStyle is supported on text fields in EXT 4.1.1, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6MxTw/

Comment: Sorry, I meant EXT 3.4.1 not 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [fieldStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-fieldStyle) (available since ExtJS 4.0) of your textfield then handle its `change` event.

```
id: 'conditionValue',
header: "Condition Value",
dataIndex: 'condValue',
width: 100,
editor: newExt.form.TextField({
    fieldStyle: 'text-transform:uppercase;',
    listeners: {
       change: function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
           field.setValue(newValue.toUpperCase());
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that once you've focused out of the text field, the field itself is hidden and its content is copied to the table cell (kinda, in fact it passes through the record and the column renderer). Add the same [CSS style](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-style) to the column and that should do it. If that's not enough, customize the column [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer).